# Allow dependent Projects to Run even if the First Project Fails in Playwright Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, playwright, playwright-test

I have a `playwright.config.ts` in which I define 3 projects. Below is my project structure.

```js
projects: [{
    name: 'Need Authentication For Usage tests',
    testDir: './tests/Billing/',
    Need Authentication For Usage tests
  },  {
    name: 'Need Authentication',
    testDir: './tests/Authentication/',
    dependencies: ['Need Authentication For Usage tests'],
  },
  {
    name: 'Non-Authentication State',
    testDir: './tests/Non-Authentication/',
    dependencies: ['Need Authentication For Usage tests'],
  },
],
```

I want to run the test scripts in `./tests/Billing/` separately and once it gets executed (be the test status be `PASS/FAIL`) then I want to run my other projects. Once the project `Need Authentication For Usage tests is completed`, only then I would want my other projects to be picked up.

I am facing this issue as I am running my tests in parallel. Is there any way through which I can achieve this?

I tried using a project structure as mentioned above, but with above project structure if any test in 'Need Authentication For Usage tests') fails other projects are skipped.

Comment: Do the [project dependencies docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#project-dependencies) help?

Comment: According to the docs if we use dependencies for a project, it will only run if the first project successfully completes execution. (i.e. only if all tests pass.) else other projects will just get skipped.

Answer (score 0):

#### Suites vs. Projects

Instead of projects , they seem to fit more in 'test suites' category which are need to be executed in a certain order. I would use Projects more in scenarios where the same set of suites need to run with different configurations on multiple devices & browsers.

#### Sort test files(Suites) alphabetically

When you disable parallel test execution, Playwright Test runs test files in alphabetical order. You can use some naming convention to control the test order.

**Example:**

001-Billing.spec.ts,

002-Authentication.spec.ts,

003-Non-Authentication.spec.ts

This way suites (test files) will run in your desired order and later suites will run even though  earlier suites fail in sequence.

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parallel#sort-test-files-alphabetically

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here my usecase is to have one test suite and run different projects in one test suite. As i dont want to generate different test results per each suite as i am pushing my reports to Report Portal. Any other workaround. (Except Running the test serially.)

Comment: No problem, I think the solution I provided would solve your issue if you give it a try.